# how to pipe to bunyan logs

Tags: node.js, logging, amazon-s3, bunyan

I'd like to create a simple logging sink that logs info to an s3 backing store using the kinesis node library https://github.com/mhart/kinesis

How do I pipe the kinesis stream into a bunyan logger?  It doesn't like the last line in this code

```
var log = bunyan.createLogger({name:"acme", stream:process.stdout})
var kinesisSource = kinesis.createReadStream('Acme', {region: 'us-east-1', oldest: true})
kinesisSource.pipe(log)
```

Also Does bunyan have a built in s3 plugin for saving/persisting log files to s3?

Comment: S3 doesn't allow streamed data. Take a look at the question linked above.